# Binding Variable Nested List to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, nested-lists

I am trying to make a multiplication table appear on a page based on input from the user.  This is my code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TableData"></asp:GridView>

List<List<int>> nestedList = new List<List<int>>();

protected void LoadTable(int val)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= val; y++)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int x = 0; x <= val; x++)
            list.Add(x * y);
        nestedList.Add(list);
    }

    TableData.DataSource = nestedList;
    TableData.DataBind();
}
```

But this displays as:

```
Capacity  Count
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
16        14
```

What am I doing wrong?

For clarification, if the user enters 5, the output should be:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  1  2  3  4  5
 0  2  4  6  8 10
 0  3  6  9 12 15
 0  4  8 12 16 20
 0  5 10 15 20 25
```

I am not worried about column or row headers at this time.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what output you're going for, but if you don't specify how the gridview should render the output, it will display one column for each public property on the type you're displaying in the grid. In this case, `List<int>` has two public properties: `Capacity` and `Count`.

Comment: I didn' understand why you use a List<List<sting>> as your items source.
Could you please tell as why ?

Comment: post `.aspx` page gridview code.

Comment: Changing it to a List<List<string>> has no affect on the output.

Comment: The output I am going for is a multiplication table, like you used to make in grade school.  The cell at row x column y is the the product of x and y.

Comment: The aspx page code is very basic since I do not know how many rows or columns I will have (this is based on user input):     <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TableData">

  </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your items Source.

a list< list < ?? > > is not a good choice (as i think).
For a Linear view you can use this approach
Code Snippet

```
            var objList = new List<object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var temp = new { operation = string.Format("{0} * {1}", i, i + 1), result = i * (i + 1) };
                objList.Add(temp);
            }
```

Comment: This code would have a fixed number of columns.  A multiplication table would have a user-defined at runtime number of columns and rows..Therefore, this approach does not help me.

Comment: @JHasell as i said it' a code snippet for a linear result

Answer (score 0):

GridView does not support 2d list binding, consider using another methode.

For exemple, use a simple List , each string will represent a row, you can fill up each string by using a loop that goes like :

```
(first loop)
{
    string s;
    for(int x = 0; x < val; x ++)
    {
        s += (x * y).Tostring() + " ");

    }
    nestedList.Add(s);
}
```